# Spring Email Using Velocity Template Engine

Tags: spring, velocity

I'm new using Spring framework and also Velocity, because that I wanna apologize if I'm missing something basic.

When I try to do something like this:

```
@Override
    public void envia(final Usuario usuario) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
            public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {     
                MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage);
                message.setTo(usuario.getEmail());
                message.setFrom("pirado2@gmail.com"); // could be parameterized...
                Map model = new HashMap();
                model.put("user", usuario);
                String text = VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(velocityEngine,
                        "/templates/registration-confirmation.vm",
                        "UTF-8",
                        model);
                message.setText(text, true);
            }
        };
        this.mailSender.send(preparator);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR [VelocityEngine      ] ResourceManager : unable to find resource '/templates/registration-confirmation.vm' in any resource loader.
```

How can I find my vm file though ?

thanks.

Comment: The problem seems to be in the Velocity configuration that you do not show and the *real* location or `templates` directory that you do not show either ... Please give more informations

Comment: I fixed it. The file wasn't in the right place.